Changing Kmls polygons using Pykml
I'm attempting to modify the color and symbology of certain files located within a folder. To accomplish this, I'm utilizing a spreadsheet containing the KML names, colors, types, thicknesses, icons, and groups. Although this code functions effectively, it only works for line and point geometries. For KML files in polygon format, the color remains unchanged.
import pykml
from lxml import etree
from pykml import parser
from pykml.factory import KML_ElementMaker as KML
import pandas as pd
import os

kml_folder = r"C:\Scripts GEO\Gerais\clip_geopandas_kml\kml"
spreadsheet = r"C:\Scripts GEO\Gerais\clip_geopandas_kml\planilha_kml.xlsx"

# Reading DataFrame outside the loop for efficiency
df = pd.read_excel(spreadsheet, sheet_name="Planilha1")

# Iterating over KML files first
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(kml_folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".kml"):
            kml_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            try:
                with open(kml_path, 'r') as f:
                    doc = parser.parse(f)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing file {kml_path}: {e}")
                continue

            # Getting the KML root element
            kml = doc.getroot()

            # Iterating over placemarks to modify the style
            for placemark in kml.iterdescendants(tag='{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Placemark'):
                try:
                    # Checking if the placemark has a name
                    name_element = placemark.find('{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}name')
                    if name_element is not None:
                        # Getting the placemark name
                        name = name_element.text.lower()

                        # Searching the spreadsheet for the corresponding style based on the placemark name
                        row = df[df['kml'].str.lower() == name]
                        print(f"Placemark Name: {name}")
                        print(f"Row: {row}")
                        if not row.empty:
                            # Getting style values from the spreadsheet
                            type = row.iloc[0]['type']
                            color = row.iloc[0]['color']
                            thickness = row.iloc[0]['thickness']
                            icon = row.iloc[0]['icon']
                            group = row.iloc[0]['group']
                            print(f"Style Found: {type}, {color}, {thickness}, {icon}, {group}")

                            # Creating style based on placemark type
                            if type == 'Polygon':
                                new_style = KML.Style(
                                    KML.PolyStyle(
                                        KML.color(str(color)),  # Color already in HEX format
                                        id="style-normal"
                                    )
                                )
                            elif type == 'Line':
                                new_style = KML.Style(
                                    KML.LineStyle(
                                        KML.color(str(color)),  # Color already in HEX format
                                        KML.width(str(thickness))
                                    )
                                )
                            elif type == 'Point':
                                new_style = KML.Style(
                                    KML.IconStyle(
                                        KML.scale("1"),
                                        KML.Icon(
                                            KML.href(str(icon))
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            else:
                                continue

                            # Removing old styles from the placemark
                            for style_element in placemark.findall('.//{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Style'):
                                placemark.remove(style_element)

                            # Adding the new style to the placemark
                            placemark.append(new_style)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error modifying Placemark style: {e}")

            # Saving the updated KML file
            new_name = f"{os.path.splitext(file)[0]}_modified.kml"
            with open(os.path.join(root, new_name), "wb") as f:
                f.write(etree.tostring(doc, encoding="utf-8"))


When I look at the output of the code, I notice that the information only appears for KMLs of type line and point; no information appears for polygons, as shown below: (164604 is a KML that is in the spreadsheet and in the folder, but the properties appear empty, although they are filled in the spreadsheet).
Placemark Name: 164604
Row: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [kml, type, color, thickness, icon, group]
Index: []
Placemark Name: alternativa_selecionada
Row: kml type color thickness icon
3 alternativa_selecionada Line F30100FF 5 NaN

I've already changed the spreadsheet format, modified variables, tried various ways of reading to recognize the cells. When I run a separate code for each KML individually, it works without any issues, inserting the color code directly without the need for a spreadsheet, as shown in the following code:
from lxml import etree
from pykml import parser
from pykml.factory import KML_ElementMaker as KML

# Load the KML file
with open(r'C:\Users\6439\Downloads\164604.kml', 'r') as f:
    doc = parser.parse(f)

# Get the root KML element
kml = doc.getroot()

# Iterate over placemarks to modify the color
for placemark in kml.iterdescendants(tag='{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Placemark'):
    # Check if the Placemark has an associated style
    
    new_style = KML.Style(
                KML.PolyStyle(
                KML.color('80add8ff'),  # Change the color to green, for example (ABGR format)
                 id="style-normal"
                
                
        ))
    placemark.append(new_style)
    # Save the updated KML file
    with open(r'C:\Users\6439\Downloads\164604_1.kml', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(etree.tostring(doc, encoding='utf-8'))
    print(KML.Style)


What could I be doing wrong in building this code?

A placemark can have either or a Style or a styleUrl. The latter uses a shared style. Did you check if your original KML using styleUrl?

Hi! how can I verify this using python? I have a list of random kml files in a folder.

Hi if you have a text editor that can do a search over multiple files (or have grep utility) search for "styleUrl" in your random collection of kml files. If you find them then you probably should remove the styleUrl element from the placement element.
